# Synchronization context not preserved in winforms event

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have the following winforms event

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new Form().ShowDialog(); // This causes the problem
}

private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadingLabel.Text = "Initializing...";

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error initializing");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(LoadingLabel.InvokeRequired);
}
```

**Expectation**: Program prints `false`.
**Result**: Program prints `true`.

It is my understanding that await should set the synchronization context back to the original and no `Invoke` should be required. However, this is not the case. Attempting to update `LoadingLabel`'s `Text` property throws an `InvalidOperationException`. Am I missing something?

I am using .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: The code is printing `false` on my machine, unless I throw in `ConfigureAwait(false)` of course. Can you reproduce this with just the code you've posted or is there anything else that might be affecting the result?

Comment: I have global variables and other functions+events, but all the code in that function is shown. The issue occurs for me with the exact code above.

Comment: @JSteward You were right. I have edited the question to include the problematic code.

Comment: `ShowDialog` isn't something typically used in a constructor because it will block until the dialog is closed. If you can wait to show your dialog until `MainForm` is loaded moving the call to `MainForm_Load` will remove the need for an `Invoke`

Comment: I need my dialog to show before the form appears. I do this in the constructor so as to set a readonly variable. Could you explain why my code results in this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the call to `ShowDialog`, which creates a nested message loop the `WindowsFormsSyncronizationContext` is replaced with the default `SyncronizationContext` causing you to need an `Invoke`. The context is then later restored. Further reading [How to get a Synchronization Context for the second form shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513021/how-to-get-a-synchronization-context-for-the-second-form-shown)

You have some options:

**(1)** Structure your code so that the call to `ShowDialog` occurs in the `Load` event or in the `OnLoad override`. I think this is the best approach and would serve you well long term.

**(2)** However, you can also do this:

```
public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    new Form().ShowDialog();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(uiContext);
}
```

This simply resets the `SyncronizationContext` back when the dialog is closed.

Comment: Adding the `.ShowDialog()` before `Application.Run(...)` in `Main` also works.